# Android TV navigation issue

Tags: navigation-drawer, android-tv, android-9.0-pie

I hope to have a discussion on an issue in Amlogic TV navigation.
There are some sort of apps which has toolbar on top of its main screen like BeeTV, Cyberflix etc.
The super parent layout is android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, and the toolbar layout is android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.
The top bar has some buttons on it including menu, favorite, search, refresh etc.

The problem is that I can select none of those buttons at all unless I have mouse plugged into the box.
Keyboard and Remote controller don't work for navigation to toolbar buttons.

The OS is Android Pie, and I confirmed Android 7.0 OS doesn't have this issue.

Is there anyone who is willing to discuss on the issue in technical aspect.
I guess AmLogic Pie frameworks might have an issue in focus management between ui elements.

Thank you in advance.